# Communication between paren-child directives in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created 2 directives, `login` and `rankSelector`. As you see from code below login is used inside of `rankSelector`. I'm not sure however what is the proper way to implement communication between these two directives? `rankSelector` is a parent of `login` and needs to know when some changes happen in `login` directive. ATM I use controller in `rankSelector` that has `passwordsMatch` method that `login` calls when it needs to inform parent directive about changes. The code is below:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="rankSelector.html">

        <form name="rankings" novalidate>

            <div>

                <div login></div>

                <!-- if passwords match show this -->

                <input type="text" ng-model="someOtherField" name="someOtherField" ng-show="passwordsMatch" ng-hide="!passwordsMatch" />

            </div>

        </form>

    </script>
```

And my directives:

```
app.directive("login", [

    function(loginService) {
        return {
            templateUrl: "login.html",
            replace: true,
            require: "?^rankSelector",
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.$watch("confirmPassword", function(newValue, oldValue) {

                    // also how in here I can check if scope.password is $valid without douing checks manually?
                    ctrl.passwordsMatch(scope.password && scope.password === scope.confirmPassword);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);

app.directive("rankSelector", [

    function(rankingsService, $rootScope) {
        return {
            templateUrl: "rankSelector.html",
            replace: true,
            controller: ["$scope",
                function($scope) {
                    this.passwordsMatch = function(showConfirm) {
                        $scope.passwordsMatch = showConfirm;
                    }
                }
            ],
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.passwordsMatch = false;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Not sure if I do the right thing here as `login` directive needs to be aware of what controller it will be inserted into. Are there any obvious problems with this approach I need to be aware of?

Also how would I possibly do the checks inside of `login` directive in `$watch` call to see if fields are `$valid` etc?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass information up the scope chain is to use events.
In your case you would have your login directive emit an event when something happens you want parent directives to react to.

```
scope.$emit('somethingChanged', anyData);
```

Then in rankSelector you would listen for the event and react to it

```
scope.$on('somethingChanged', function($event, anyData) {
    // react to the change
})
```